# Getting core dumps when freeing dynamic string array

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays, coredump

I am trying to create a shell that takes user input and can execute Linux and built-in commands, and up until this point everything has been fine. My problem is that my function for executing piping commands sometimes core dumps. I know that it is core dumping when I'm iterating through the char** array to free each index, but it only core dumps every now and again.

Here is my function with some debug print statements.

```
int getCommand(int index, char** commands, char **args, int size){
    int i = 0;

    for(i; i < size && args[index] != NULL && strcmp(args[index],"|"); i++{
        commands[i] = strdup(args[index]);
        index++;
    }
    if(i < size)
        commands[i] = NULL;

    if(index < size && args[index] != NULL && !strcmp(args[index],"|"))
        index++;
    return index;
}

void pipe(char **args, int size, int numOfPipes){
    char **commands = malloc(size*sizeof(char**));
    int index = 0;
    int new_fd[2], old_fd[2], status;
    pid_t pid;

    for(int i = 0; i < (numOfPipes+1); i++){
        index = getCommand(index, commands, args, size);
        if(pipe(new_fd[2] == -1){
            printf("Pipe failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if((pid = fork()) < 0){
            printf("Fork failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if(pid == 0){
            if(i > 0){
                dup2(old_fd[0],0);
                close(old_fd[1]);
            }
            if(i < numOfPipes){
                dup2(new_fd[1],1);
                close(new_fd[0]);
            }
            if(execvp(*commands,commands) < 0){
                printf("Command could not be executed.");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        else{
                close(old_fd[0]);
                close(old_fd[1]);

                wait(&status);

                old_fd[0] = new_fd[0];
                old_fd[1] = new_fd[1];
        }

    printf("Free strings\n");
    /* Here is where it core dumps */
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%d\n",i);
        free(commands[i]);
    }

    printf("Freeing pointer\n");
    free(commands);
}
```

Can anyone help me see where I am going wrong?

Comment: `char **commands = malloc(size*sizeof(char**));` - Straight off the bat this is a mistake.

Comment: `getCommand` -> This code would be handy

Comment: @EdHeal added getCommand function

Comment: After allocating  memory for char **commands, where do you allocate memory for each index?

Comment: @nabil.douss my understanding is that `strdup()` allocates the space using `malloc()`, so it should be allocating that space in the for loop inside `getCommand` when I'm copying the strings to the index in my commands array

Comment: the posted code doesn't even come close to compiling, much less cleanly compiling!  We will have a very difficult time guess about what your actual code contains.  When asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: regarding: `char **commands = malloc(size*sizeof(char**));` the parameter to `malloc()` should be of type `size_t`  (long unsigned).  However, this parameter is multiplying a `int` times a `size_t`  I.E. multiplying a signed value times a unsigned value.  This will cause the compiler to output a warning.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2)  separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line.

Comment: the function name: `pipe` is a well known c function.  The code should not be using well known function names for the user written functions.  Regarding: `void pipe(char **args, int size, int numOfPipes) .... if(pipe(new_fd[2] == -1){`  are you expecting this function to be 'recursive'?  Probably not, since they have different signatures

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) insert appropriate spaces after commas, after semicolons, inside parens, around C operators.

Comment: the `exec` functions only return if they failed to create the new process.  I.E. this: `if(execvp(*commands,commands) < 0){` can be simplified to: `execvp( *commands, commands );`

Comment: regarding `printf("Command could not be executed.");` and similar statements.  When outputting an error message, output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  When outputting an error message due to some system function, like `exec()` or `pipe()` or ... use `perror()` so both the enclosed text and the text of the reason the system thinks the error occurred are output

Comment: regarding: `for(i; i < size && args[index] != NULL && strcmp(args[index],"|"); i++{`  1)  the `for()` statement is missing the closing paren ')'  2) the first parameter has no action, so should be blank.

Comment: regarding: `if(pipe(new_fd[2] == -1){`  this is not valid syntax.  Suggest: `if( pipe( new_fd[2] ) == -1 ){`   Remember, opening and closing parens must balance

Comment: regarding: `if(i < numOfPipes){` This will ALWAYS be true. because 'i' is being controlled by the preceeding `for()` statement.

Comment: regarding: ` }  printf("Free strings\n");`  this is missing a closing brace.  It should be: `}   }  printf("Free strings\n");`  The result is the heap allocations are passed to `free()` on every iteration of the `for()` loop!  This is probably why the code (if it runs at all) is producing a seg fault event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there are two problems :

1. because of the condition in the for-loop in  `getCommand`, `strdup` is not guaranteed to be called `size` times, and therefore not all elements of the array `commands` will be initialized.

I suggest that you check if the elements aren't `NULL` before freeing them :

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    if (command[i] != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n",i);
        free(commands[i]);
    }
}
```

2.
Because of the for-loop in the `pipe` function, `getCommand` is being called `numOfPipes` times and possibly allocating new memory every time for the `command` array elements , without freeing the previous allocated memory. 
I suggest you check and free the memory before calling`getCommand` (or `strdup`)

Comment: If these issues are the case, could this also be avoided by initializing each index with `malloc` and then using `strcpy` instead of using `strdup`? Would I still have an issue with freeing an index that equals `NULL`?

Comment: If you use malloc on all of them once and then free them once. then yes, you shouldn't receive any error (as long as malloc didn't return `NULL`)

Comment: Remember  that the function: `free()`  specifically checks for NULL and handles it properly.  So a pointer being NULL is not the problem.  However, a pointer not being initialized (so it contains garbage) is the problem.